# How to print specific array element of SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I want to fetch results from the response of any array. Here is the Array output:

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
       [GetCharitiesByKeywordResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [GetCharitiesByKeywordResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [CharityList] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [RegisteredCharityNumber] => 1175358
                                [SubsidiaryNumber] => 0
                                [CharityName] =>  LYDIARD PARK HERITAGE TRUST                                                                                                                          
                                [MainCharityName] =>  LYDIARD PARK HERITAGE TRUST                                                                                                                          
                                [RegistrationStatus] => Registered
                                [PublicEmailAddress] => info@lydiardtrust.org.uk
                                [MainPhoneNumber] => 07763059645
                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [RegisteredCharityNumber] => 1188662
                                [SubsidiaryNumber] => 0
                                [CharityName] =>  PALACE THEATRE & OPERA HOUSE TRUST                                                                                                                   
                                [MainCharityName] =>  PALACE THEATRE & OPERA HOUSE TRUST                                                                                                                   
                                [RegistrationStatus] => Registered
                                [PublicEmailAddress] => SheenaWrigley@theambassadors.com
                                [MainPhoneNumber] => 01612456636
                            )
```

I am trying to print the 'Charity Name' of first element by the below code but I got null value:

```
print "<br>Result = ". $parser['GetCharitiesByKeywordResponse']['GetCharitiesByKeywordResult']['CharityList']['0']['CharityName'];
```

Need help to get it printed.

thanks

Comment: wonder why someone give negative rating to my question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an object, not an array.

Try it with this:

```php
$parser->GetCharitiesByKeywordResponse->GetCharitiesByKeywordResult->CharityList[0]->CharityName;
```